# Items in a WrapPanel; given one item, how to determine 'surrounding' items (above, below, left, right)?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I've written a custom ItemsControl, whose children are laid out within a WrapPanel.  My ItemsControl has a concept of a "Selected Item," and I would like to allow users to change their selection using keyboard keys in any of four directions: up, down, left or right.

It's easy to move the selection left and right; I just "select" the previous (or next) item in the collection.  But what if I want to move *up* or *down*?  I need to first determine which item exists directly above or below my currently-selected item.

Are there existing APIs in WPF which will 'figure out' which element lies below or above a given control?  Or do I need to calculate this stuff by hand?

Comment: There is no api concept of a line in wrappanel that I'm aware of, so I would be very surprised if such a thing exists out of the box.

Comment: this behavior is good but only when the items are laid out like as in a uniform grid. Otherwise it's hard to determine which one is exactly  above or below the current item (because the vertical-alignment is not lined-up along the items). Anyway if you want to implement this, I suggest using hit testing (look into `VisualTreeHelper`). You just need to estimate the point on the left, on the right, above or below  the current and let `VisualTreeHelper` help you which item is at that point. Of course the item type (or any kind of identification) should be known.